# Spring transaction with hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, transactions

So I have the following issue with transactions and oracle 11g XE using Spring Transactions with annotations.

Transaction T1 starts, reads record A from the DB.

Transaction T2 starts, modifies record A and then commits.
In transaction T1, after T2 committs, I read record A again from the DB and I get the same result as the first time, without the changes committed by T2.

I use the default configuration for transaction T1 and `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` for T2

On the second read I would like to see the changes done by T2.

Is this possible? Am I missing something ?

From what I understand, the default isolation is READ_COMMITTED and this should allow for T1 to read the committed changes.

Thank you

Comment: You said, T2 starts, modifies records and commits. Okay, is T1 executing in parallel and you get the same result as first-time, before T2 commited? Right, then, that's normal. If the record is not modified(read committed), why do you expect that T1 will have updated information.

Comment: If it happens from the same session, you well get the cached version. So you aren't reading from the database but the hibernate first level cache.

Comment: You can use refresh(entity) to load current state from the database. http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/EntityManager/refresh_Object

Comment: @WeareBorg The second read in T1 is after T2 committed.

Comment: @M.Deinum shouldn't the 1st level cache be updated by T2 ?

Comment: Then you are receiving a cache version as M.Denium already mentioned. Also, correct your text so it's better for understanding.  If you try them in a different transactions, this wont happen. Or flush the session then do a read. I believe what you are mentioning is called as RAW hazard(Comp arch term).

Comment: No. The first level cache is basically the session (or entity manager if you use JPA) as long as you use the same session (or haven't cleared it) you will receive the cached instance.